# Using Tree structure, check if two given expressions are equal

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, expression-trees

### Problem

I have two expressions.

Only two operators are used: + and *. (Example: (a + b), (a * b) are valid expressions).

I'm supposed to write a program that would determine if these two expressions are equal.

Example:

1. Expression 1: (a + b)*c = a*c + b*c;
2. Expression 2: c*(a + b) = c*a + c*b = a*c + b*c;

Conclusion: Expression 1 and 2 are equal.

---

### Note:

***I've got the following indications:***

Bring these two expressions in "sum of products" form, sort the terms of the sum, and then check if the expressions are equal.
I should use tree structure to accomplish this task:

1. Create [Expression Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) for each of two expressions
2. For each Tree of the two resulted (from point 1) create another tree, that would represent "the sum of products" form of the respective expression.

---

### What I already know

I've already written programs that create [Expression Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree).
I have experience working with trees.

---

### Question

Can you, please, suggest me an algorithm that would solve this problem ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need first to search for cases where you have a multiplication node above an addition node. When you find replace the structure there so that the addition is on top. Do this until you don't find any such cases anymore.

Now your tree should look like a sum of products. Take each product and flip left and right children so that they are sorted. The exact criteria doesn't matter but you should always get the same structure for a product term like abc(note that should also compare terms to nodes, and maybe rotate terms, so that can fix (ab)c and a(bc) to the same structure). When you're done, do the same for the addition above.

Do this for both expression trees, when you're done just compare if you got the exact same tree.